# How to use Angular Material Autocomplete, Chip, Checkbox together?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let vdr of vdrs | quickFilter: auto_ctrl | slice:0:500 ;let i = index"
                            [value]="vdr">
                            <mat-checkbox  [disabled]="vdr_chips.length>=5" (change)="toggleSelection($event,vdr)"
                                (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                                {{vdr}}
                            </mat-checkbox>
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
```

I have to implement autocomplete and chip functionality and add checkboxes inside it for multiple selection. Currently I have implemented automcomplete and chip input using the Angular Material Docs.

Comment: So now you just want to implement only checkboxes inside options? Or need more?

Comment: There is no way to make multi select with MatAutocomplete, mainly for one reason - when item gets selected, overlay is being closed. I had to create my custom solution for this, without using MatAutocomplete

Comment: No, there is no way. Others uses `setTimeout` to open it again, but thats not a good solution as it recreates all nodes again on every selection

Comment: I have successfully implemented the above 3 together but the issue with the drop-down persists.